# iOS 16 以降で非推奨となった NavigationLink の isActive の代わりの書き方は？

Tags: swift, ios, swiftui

iOS16からNavigationLinkのisActiveが非推奨になっています。
しかし、新しい文法でisActiveの代わりになる書き方を見つけられません。
どなたか解決案をお持ちでしょうか。
ログイン成功後に自動で画面遷移などよくあるようなパターンだと思います。
現在はNavigationLinkのisActiveで制御しています。

Comment: 当サイトは日本語でのやり取りを前提としているので、英語の併記は不要です。(今回はこちらで編集しておきました)

Comment: ありがとうございます。英語圏の方にもと思い英語併記していました

Comment: 英語で質問したい場合は https://stackoverflow.com/ に投稿してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

遷移後にボタンを押すことで得るデータが必要なければ`navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:)`で実装可能です。

データが必要であれば`navigationDestination(for:destination:)`が利用可能です。

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var isPresented = false

  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      Button("Next") {
        isPresented.toggle()
      }
      .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isPresented) {
        Text("Next")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`NavigationView`と`NavigationLink`の組み合わせが`Deprecated`になったので代わりに`NavigationStack`を使います。

Appleのドキュメントにあるように`NavigtionLink`の`isActive`で制御するのではなく`NavigationStack`の状態を示す配列を使ってそこに値を積むことで画面遷移をコントロールします。

```swift
@State private var presentedParks: [Park] = []

NavigationStack(path: $presentedParks) {
    List(parks) { park in
        NavigationLink(park.name, value: park)
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: Park.self) { park in
        ParkDetails(park: park)
    }
}

func showParks() {
    presentedParks = [Park("Yosemite"), Park("Sequoia")]
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack?changes=_8

（参考）
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

Comment: Xcodeにて動きを確認しました。NavigationStackにバインディングされた配列内に要素が追加されるタイミングで画面遷移されるようですね。Listに指定されているparksは画面遷移するであろうParkが入っているということでいいですかね？